# Rails Active Record starts with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a variable called `letters` which in this instance equals the following:

```
["a", "e"]
```

Basically, how can I perform an active record query on my `Item`'s model to find all Items that start with A, B, C, D & E?

Comment: Could you be more elaborate? I can understand that Item is a model. What are the attributes of Item? and which attribute should start with a, b, c, d & e?

Comment: Ok, So the Item model has an attribute called 'name' and it is this attribute I want to filter on

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL is the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this link: http://programming-tut.blogspot.ca/2009/10/ruby-on-rails-loop-alphabet-to-z.html

You could do that:

```
range = [ 'A', 'E' ]
conditions = (range.first..range.last).to_a.map{ |letter| " name ILIKE '#{letter}%' " }.join('OR')
Item.where(conditions)
```

Or like Vimsha pointed out:

```
letters = ('A'..'E').to_a
Item.where("substr(name, 1, 1) IN (?)", letters)
```

Comment: Thanks, Just tried this: @items = Item.where("substr(name, 1, 1) IN (?)", letters) but I get no results. I have confirmed the letters variable and thats fine. Results should be being returned. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just tried some more ideas but they all return an empty array. Any ideas?

Comment: is `'a'..'e'.to_a` producing an array like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`? Did you try with the `.map`? This is also case sensitive, you may need to fix that to get results.

Comment: Yes, the map method worked perfectly. Made a few adjustments to suit but thanks! Now what is not working is that I have two filters that get checked. If both filters are enabled then it filters down the Items based on the first one and then should use the results of the first filter as the basis to filter from the second. But it doesn't like me calling .where on the instance variable of @items which is being passed to my view? Any thoughts?

Comment: This problem is not described in this question, you should create a new one for this issue. Also, you should accept an answer if it fits your (initial) question @rctneil

Comment: Ok, will create a new question now. I was going to accept an answer of course, but was waiting until I got it working before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Item.where("substr(name, 1, 1) in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')")